# Showing data from api in .xib not working

Tags: ios, swift, api, alamofire, xib

I used .xib file to create multiple `UICollectionView` / `UITableview` within single `UIViewController` it was working fine with dummy data. But now I want to integrate API into the .nib. I am facing the issue that my `getDataForBannerImage()` execute but and it should return `bannerImageModel` from service but it always returning 0 count of bannerImageModel I am unable to rectify the issue please help me

```
class BannerImageStatus: Decodable {
    let status: String
    let error: Bool
    let data: [BannerImageModel]
    init(status: String, error: Bool, data: [BannerImageModel]) {
        self.status = status
        self.error = error
        self.data = data
    }
}

class BannerImageModel: Decodable {
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var image: String
    var url: String
    var status: String
    var created_at: String

    init(id: String, name: String, image: String, url: String, status: String, created_at: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.image = image
        self.url = url
        self.status = status
        self.created_at = created_at
    }
}  


class BannerImageService {
    var bannerImageModel = [BannerImageModel]()



        func getDataForBannerImage() -> [BannerImageModel]  {
            Alamofire.request("http://abcd/Homeapi/banner/format/json/").responseJSON{ response in
            if let locationJSON = response.result.value as? [String: Any] {
                let data = locationJSON["data"] as! [[String: Any]]
                for dataItem in data {
                    let bannerModel = BannerImageModel(id: dataItem["id"] as! String, name: dataItem["name"] as! String, image: dataItem["image"] as! String, url: dataItem["url"] as! String, status: dataItem["status"] as! String, created_at: dataItem["created_at"] as! String)
                    self.bannerImageModel.append(bannerModel)
                    print(bannerModel.url + bannerModel.image)
                }
            }
        }
        return bannerImageModel
    }
```

Now when I am calling service from .xib class always bannerImageModelArray.count giving 0 because of this problem I am not able to call my collection view

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    //bannerImageService.getDataForBannerImage()
    bannerImageModelArray = bannerImageService.getDataForBannerImage()
    print(bannerImageModelArray.count)
    print(bannerImageService.bannerImageModel.count)
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("BannerView", owner: self, options: nil)
    self.addSubview(self.view)
    let nibName = UINib(nibName: "BannerCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)
    bannerCollectionView.register(nibName, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "BannerCollectionViewCell")
    bannerCollectionView.dataSource = self
    bannerCollectionView.delegate = self
    bannerCollectionView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    startTimer()
}
```

Comment: What is that? `func getDataForBannerImage()  {
    func getDataForBannerImage() -> [BannerImageModel]  {`   And if you use Codable you don't need to parse response manually

Comment: It will return the list of image from api

Comment: Why you have function inside function? Your first function not returning list go images.

Comment: Remove this: `func getDataForBannerImage()  {}` and leave this `func getDataForBannerImage() -> [BannerImageModel]  {}`

Comment: That was mistake while typing in stack overflow

Comment: Your call to the API is asynchronous. `grtDataForBannerImage()` returns before data is actually retrieved and processed. This is a good thing, as otherwise your main thread would get blocked and your app would be unreaponsive. You need to restructure your code to accomodate for that. There are many good tutorials/articles about handling asynchronous API calls in iOS/Swift.